# Tooltip with Fontawesome Icons

Tags: jsf, primefaces, font-awesome

I want to use [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) for a tooltip text, but I don't know how to implement it. It worked with a overlay Panel but I want to use the `<p:tooltip>` tag.

I use primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.1
Here is the Code with the tooltip

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p:graphicImage id="grap" class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x"/>
<p:tooltip for="grap" value="Some Help" showEffect="fade" />
```

If I use the following it works

```
<h:panelGroup id="mail" class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x" />
 <p:overlayPanel for="mail" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout" hideEffect="fade">
   <p:panel>
         TEXTTEXTTEXT
   </p:panel>
  </p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: Must work by accident, then. Try the `styleClass` attribute instead of the `class`.

Comment: Nothing is displayed if I use styleClass

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. It works on Primefaces 6.0 and JSF 2.3.0.

```
<p:outputLabel id ="idEmptyLabel">
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x"/>
</p:outputLabel>
<p:tooltip for="idEmptyLabel" value="It works!" />
```

Comment: Nope. When you hover to the icon and the tooltip will pop up. That's what @bvb1909 asked.

Answer (score 0):

@Dylan Law's solution will definitely work.

However, if you do not always want to wrap your standard HTML elements such as `<i>`, `<span>`, `<img>` and `<div>` you can follow this strategy:

Define the following line in a template or a file:

```
<p:tooltip globalSelector="a,:input,:button,span,img,i,div" />
```

`globalSelector` is under the hood a jQuery selector, that defaults to `a,:input,:button`. Hence, I also added these also to my custom selector.

Now you you can simply write for example:

```
<i class="fas fa-info-circle" title="This will be the content of the tooltip">
```

Here you can read more about Global Tooltips:
https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/tooltip?id=global-tooltip